# Minimum Vertex Cover of Tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Aim - To find the minimum vortex cover of a tree.
Given an unweighted, undirected tree, find it's minimum vortex cover. Having checked if the Graph is Bipartite or not and also made the 2 sets of vertices, is it true the minimum of these 2 sets returns the minimum cover. 
If yes, what seems to be the error in the following code? The same code successfully passed the below mentioned question on a Codeforces contest, however it would give a WA if used (with slight modification as per the input) for the mentioned Spoj problem.

And yes, obvious changes in the output format were made while submitting on Spoj.

Codeforces question to check if Bipartite or not.

http://www.codeforces.com/problemset/problem/688/C

My submission

`enter code here`http://ideone.com/PwduxV

Question on spoj to find the minimum cover.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07X/

Comment: Please explain the issue in more detail. The problems are quite different; the SPOJ problem is 'easy' in the sense as you describe, namely generating a 2-coloring (which exists as trees are bipartite) and returning the smaller color class. However, the Codeforces problem asks for generation of 2 disjoint vertext covers of an arbitrary graph, which apparently are not even guaranteed to exist (as can be seen via the complete graph on 3 vertices).

Comment: What Codeforces wants is to check if the graph is bipartite, if yes, then print the 2 disjoint sets. For spoj, it is ensured bipartition exists since we are given a tree. So just finding out the 2 sets as done at Codeforces and printing the one with the smaller size, would this not suffice as correct?

Comment: That is quite insightful; do you mean that in the Codeforces formulation, the two vertex covers would be the partitions, which would prove the input to be bipartite? If so, the title `NP`-hard problem is highly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

An undirected tree is always bipartite, but it's not guaranteed that one of the sets will be the minimum cover.

Consider the simple graph:

```
1-3
2-3
3-4
4-5
4-6
```

The minimum cover is {3,4}, but you can divide it into bipartite sets {1,2,4}, {3,5,6}